# Simulating the collision of particles inside a box in Julia

Tags: julia, collision-detection, linear-algebra, particles

I would like to code a function (lets call it `update!`), that updates the position and velocity of particles inside a box.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I already have a function that describes the collision between two particles.

```
mutable struct Particle
    pos :: Vector{Float64}
    vel :: Vector{Float64}
end

p1 = Particle( rand(2) , rand(2) )
p2 = Particle( rand(2) , rand(2) )
```

```
function collision!(p1::Particle, p2::Particle)
     
    # Find collision vector
    n = p1.pos - p2.pos
    
    # Normalize it, since you want an orthonormal basis
    n ./= sqrt(n[1]^2 + n[2]^2)
    
    # Construct M
    M = [n[1] n[2]; -n[2] n[1]]
    
    # Find transformed velocity vectors
    v1ₙ = M*p1.vel
    v2ₙ = M*p2.vel
    
    # Swap first component 
    v1ₙ[1], v2ₙ[1] = v2ₙ[1], v1ₙ[1]
    
    # Calculate and store new velocity vectors
    p1.vel .= M'*v1ₙ
    p2.vel .= M'*v2ₙ
    
    return nothing
end
```

I know that the function `update!` has to:

1. find out if the particles are not too close (they cant be closer then 2*Radius, like shown in the image above).
2. Only consider the relevant particles. 
   For a particle p1 we can go through all the possible collisions with other particles, by using `collsion!`.
3. See if the particle is inside the box, if not then it "bounces" off the walls of the box. 
   (I know that this can be done using `xlims, ylims`)

```
function update!(particles, xlims, ylims, dt)
    
    for p1 in particles 
        
        # loop through pairs in order to find collisions
        
        for p2 in # ...
            
        # ... #
        
        # walls
        # ... #
        
    end

    # positions update
    # ...  #
        
end
```

4. Finally There should be another function, that defines the Number of particles , box size, time intervalls dt and the amount of time that the simulation is running.

```
function particles_in_box!(particles, xlims, ylims, T, dt=0.01)
 
    # ... #
    
end
```

I think I got the theory right, but I am not sure how to implement it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please try to come up with something more specific than "I am not sure how to proceed". That is, unfortunately, not a suitable question. Maybe try to break down your problem.

Comment: The 2D case was implemented by DynamicalBillards.jl, so you may want to review that code.